# Sending an ZPL Label to a Zebra printer

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I want to send a text file containing ZPL to a Zebra GC420 printer. The ZPL Manual asks me to send it to the printer from the DOS command prompt, but doesn't say how. I can send through the parallel port using PRN, and it works. But I cannot print through USB, and I cannot print from any Windows version above XP.

Comment: try this http://superuser.com/questions/182655/how-do-i-simulate-a-parallel-lpt-printer-with-a-usb-printer  or this http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/286613-30-printer-lpt1

Comment: I found a very simple solution, to share the printer on the network, and then copy the file to that printer. Unfortunately this is a non-solution as now anyone can print to this printer. Any way to stop that would be an answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

1. make zpl commmand text file
2. type 'copy printsample.txt lpt1' in dos command window

Comment: 3. comport => copy printsample.txt com1

Answer (score 0):

In the network printer, you can use the `netcat (nc)`. It is available in Linux and in [windows too](https://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows/).

```
netcat -N your.printer.ip 9100 <text_file_you_want
```

I checked it few minutes ago...